# Unable to send parameters to cmd.exe through ShellExecuteEx()

Tags: c++, mfc, 7zip, shellexecuteex

I want my MFC-C++ program to open cmd.exe and run 7-zip in command line which takes in several parameters.

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShRun = {0};
ShRun.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShRun.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShRun.hwnd = NULL;
ShRun.lpVerb = NULL;
ShRun.lpFile = _T("c:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
ShRun.lpParameters = _T("C:\\tmp\\7zip-command line\\7za920\\7za e C:\cpp\zipping\*.tar *.png -r -o"C:\tmp\7zip-command line\7za920"");
ShRun.lpDirectory = _T("c:\\windows\\System32");
ShRun.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShRun.hInstApp = NULL;

// Execute the file with the parameters
if (!ShellExecuteEx(&ShRun))
{
    MessageBox(_T("Unable to open file!"));
}
```

If I just execute 
"C:\tmp\7zip-command line\7za920\7za" e C:\cpp\zipping*.tar *.
png -r -o"C:\tmp\7zip-command line\7za920"
by pasting it in command window, it works fine. But, I am not able to execute the same through my program. 
Please note command-line version of 7-zip, "7za.exe" is in the folder path "C:\tmp\7zip-command line\7za920"
I would like to also know if it's correct decision that I have made to use ShellExecuteEx() instead of CreateProcess() and is there any other way to solve my problem. Please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're properly escaping all your backslashes in `lpParameters`. I don't think your snippet should even compile...

Comment: Yes. That' true.. It does not compile.. I was just trying out with "C:\tmp\7zip-command line\7za920\7za.exe", it compiles, but no command comes in the cmd.exe window.

Comment: @computerfreaker: Please let me know how to proceed with it..

Comment: If you try running cmd from the Start Menu, you'll note that just passing it a parameter isn't enough to make it execute that parameter as a command. `cmd C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe` opens the command-line window but does nothing else. Try using the `/C` flag: for example, `cmd /C C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe` opens the command-line window and runs notepad from it.